# How do I insert function argument "key" instead of variable "$key1" in json_encode?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

$date_range_list['week'][$key1]['option'] : This is an associative array which is being passed to the blade.php template.

The function shown below is a JavaScript function.

function durationClick(btnValue, key, index) {

```
                    if ( btnValue == "week"){
                        ops = {!!json_encode($date_range_list['week'][$key1]['option']) !!};
                    }else if( btnValue == "month" ){
                        ops = {!!json_encode($date_range_list['month'][$key1]['option']) !!};
                    }else if( btnValue == "halfYear" ){
                        ops = {!!json_encode($date_range_list['halfYear'][$key1]['option']) !!};
                    }else if( btnValue == "year" ){
                        ops = {!!json_encode($date_range_list['year'][$key1]['option']) !!};
                    }else if( btnValue == "all" ){
                        ops = {!!json_encode($question['option']) !!};
                    }
```

}

Comment: Is this JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please update your question with more details or it will be closed and/or downvoted. Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a JavaScript Function. However, the variable $Key1 is a php variable

Comment: Your *attempt of question* is totally unclear, it doesn't meet Stackoverflow's requirements, please improve it. We don't want to welcome new members just by closing their questions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot influence PHP variables by executing JavaScript functions like this (at least an AJAX request is required).

Try to send all the data to the client, if possible, and use it already in this form. For example

```
const date_range_list = {!!json_encode($date_range_list) !!};

function durationClick(btnValue, key, index) {
  if ( btnValue == "week"){
    ops = date_range_list.week[key].option;
  }else if( btnValue == "month" ){
    ops = date_range_list.month[key].option;
  }else if( btnValue == "halfYear" ){
    ops = date_range_list.halfYear[key].option;
  }else if( btnValue == "year" ){
    ops = date_range_list.year[key].option;
  }else if( btnValue == "all" ){
    ops = {!!json_encode($question['option']) !!};
  }
}
```